# GetDetailsOf fails to work when "hide extensions for known file types" is selected

Tags: windows, file, vbscript, metadata

Consider the following VBScript which, when run, lists all the files in the current directory and their properties:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oShell : Set oShell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace(oFSO.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName))
Dim oFile, iPos, sHeader(999), sVal
' Get a list of the property names
For iPos = 0 to 999
    sHeader(iPos) = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFolder.Items, iPos)
Next
' For each file in this folder, print the property name and the value
For Each oFile in oFolder.Items
    WScript.Echo "Looking at " & oFile.Name
    For iPos = 0 To 999
        sVal = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFolder.ParseName(oFile.Name), iPos)
        If sVal <> "" Then WScript.Echo sHeader(iPos) & " (" & iPos & "): " & sVal
    Next
Next
```

If I run this in a folder that contains only this file and with the Windows setting "**Hide extensions for known file types**" disabled, then I get the following (correct) output:

```
D:\defect>cscript //NOLOGO list_metadata.vbs
Looking at list_metadata.vbs
Name (0): list_metadata.vbs
Size (1): 740 bytes
Item type (2): VBScript Script File
Date modified (3): 19/02/2012 12:26
Date created (4): 23/02/2012 22:16
Date accessed (5): 23/02/2012 22:16
Attributes (6): A
Perceived type (9): Unspecified
Owner (10): HOME\Richard
Kind (11): Program
Rating (19): Unrated
Computer (53): HOME (this computer)
Filename (155): list_metadata.vbs
Shared (173): No
Folder name (176): defect
Folder path (177): D:\defect
Folder (178): defect (D:)
Path (180): D:\defect\list_metadata.vbs
Type (182): VBScript Script File
Link status (188): Unresolved
Sharing status (269): Not shared
```

However if I run this again with "**Hide extensions for known file types**" enabled, then the value for each item is exactly the same as the property and the name of the file in the first line is missing the extension:

```
D:\defect>cscript //NOLOGO list_metadata.vbs
Looking at list_metadata
Name (0): Name
Size (1): Size
Item type (2): Item type
Date modified (3): Date modified
...lots deleted...
Frame width (285): Frame width
Total bitrate (286): Total bitrate
Masters Keywords (debug) (287): Masters Keywords (debug)
Masters Keywords (debug) (288): Masters Keywords (debug)
```

Does anyone know how I can modify this code so that it will work irrespective of whether or not this setting is applied in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Name` property is the display name, not the file name. For the file name, use the `Path` property. But why are you extracting the name from the item, and then parsing the name back into an item? Why not just use the item directly?

```
sVal = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFile, iPos)
```